# Auto closing brackets in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Maybe I used a wrong shortcut, but my VS code does not close brackets ans parenthesis anymore

For example, when I typed : `function (`, VSCode used to close it automatically (`function()`). Same with brackets.

In my settings, "auto closing brackets" is on Always.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution !
The problem was the extension : GitHub Copilot.

Copilot settings are not compatible with default VSCode settings.